# Threading in C#. Interruptable task

Tags: c#, concurrency

In my program i have some very long task, which should be interruptable from GUI (WPF). Any advices about threading architecture?

This task looks like N thread with such code:

```
public void DoLongOperation()
{
    for(int i=beginPoint; i<endPoint; i++)
    {
       doSomethingStupid(dataArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx); specifically, [WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx).  There is an example of what you want to do at [WPF Multithreading: Using the BackgroundWorker and Reporting the Progress to the UI](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/).

Comment: Yeah, really useful and simple. I knew about this class, but never used it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

.Interrupt() on a thread is not the good way, the only good way is with a bool as you say in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can either check to see if it should be stopped, each loop iteration, by checking a bool. Or just .interrupt() it, and handle the exception (if it's safe for it to be killed at any time).